# JUnit test with JPA & Hibernate : Persistence.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

I'm working with 3 layers : Services, Business and Persistence. I want to test each layer. So, I create a src/test/java folder with my test file and a src/test/resources for persistence files (persistence.xml and data.sql). I set this two folders in each layer. But when I want to test the business layer, I got the following errors :

```
SEVERE - Unable to load Persistence Unit from EAR: C:\dev\prj\myProject\persistence\\classpath.ear, module: file:/c:/dev/myProject/persistence/target/classes/. Exception: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence", local:"persistence"). Expected elements are <{http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1063)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:150)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:619)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3129)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.jpa.unit.JaxbPersistenceFactory.getPersistence(JaxbPersistenceFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors.deploy(ReadDescriptors.java:180)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:971)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:832)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.getOpenEjbConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:546)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.getOpenEjbConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:591)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.getOpenEjbConfiguration(Assembler.java:484)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:463)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:151)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:68)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:309)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:289)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.loader.OpenEJBInstance.init(OpenEJBInstance.java:36)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory.init(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory.init(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:46)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at be.smals.dos.engine.persistence.test.WorkflowDaoTest.setUp(WorkflowDaoTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

After a few researches, it seems that we cannot have more than one persistence.xml.
To resolve the problem, I tried following solutions :

1. Replace the xml file of the business layer to the persistence layer. So the test run the persistence.xml of the business layer.

```html
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.8</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
  <id>copy-test-persistence</id>
  <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>run</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <tasks>
   <!-- backup the "src" persistence.xml -->
   <move file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"
      tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.src"/>
   <!-- copy the "test" persistence.xml -->
   <copy file="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"
      tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
   <!-- backup the "src" dos-engine-data.sql -->
   <move file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/data.sql"
      tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/data.sql.src"/>
   <!-- copy the "test" dos-engine-data.sql -->
   <copy file="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/data.sql"
      tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/data.sql"/>
    </tasks>
  </configuration>
   </execution>
   <execution>
  <id>restore-persistence</id>
  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>run</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <tasks>
   <!-- restore the "src" persistence.xml -->
   <move file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.src"
      tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
   <!-- restore the "src" dos-engine-data.sql -->
   <move file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/data.sql.src"
      tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/data.sql"/>
    </tasks>
  </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

2. Creation of a second jar but without any persistence.xml. And indicate that when we run test we have to use those JAR.

```html
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <phase>package</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>jar</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <finalName>jarName</finalName>
    <includes>
     <include>pathWithPersistenceFile</include>
    </includes>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
  <execution>
   <phase>package</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>jar</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <finalName>jarNameTest</finalName>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
    <includes>
     <include>pathWithoutPersistenceFile</include>
    </includes>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Those two solution aren't working in my case. Is there an other issue to work with more than one persistence.xml ? Is there maybe an solution to specify an other persistence file path but without Spring ? In this project, I'm working with Maven, Hibernate and H2 mem.

I spend several days to find a solution for my specific problem, but I don't find something helpful for my problem.

Anyone any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you test each layer by mocking other layers?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using different XML namespaces in the `main` and `test` targets? The XML namespace was changed between JPA 2.0 and 2.1. See here http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/index.html

Comment: @Jobin, thank you for your answer.

But I can't Mock the other layers because I need the really behavior of the others layers too.

Comment: @coladict, I already use different XML namespaces int the main and test targets, because JUnit need the 1.0 version.

Comment: @bibi are you using spring?

Comment: @Jobin No, I don't use Spring

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use Arquillian e.g: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/integrationtesting-487452.html

when creating your Archive, you can overwrite the persistence.xml by doing

```
ShrinkWrap.addAsResource("your-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
```

That way you can have as many your-persistence.xml as you want, and simply re-overwrite it in individual test suit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it this project I can't use Arquillian.